# Are questions about trying to find JTAG pinouts for specific mobile devices on topic?

Tags: discussion

What if I asked for a JTAG pinout for a specific make and model of cell phone? Would this be on topic here?

Answer (score 4):

So your question can be interpreted in a couple of ways/intents, and I'll address those individually. You can either clarify or make the decision for yourself.

If you are asking *"Does anyone have the JTAG pinout of my phone"*, that will probably be closed because it is not about electronics *design*. In this case, the chances that someone here would have the JTAG pinout are low, and there is a much better chance you would find such information using [Google](http://www.google.com/).

If you are asking *"How can I find JTAG pins on my phone"*, that is a better question for the StackExchange format. However, it still isn't a good fit for our site, as it still isn't about electronics *design*. Consider trying to ask your question on the [Reverse Engineering](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/) site.

Finally, if you are asking *"How can I identify JTAG pin functions given this unlabeled JTAG header?"* then that may get a decent answer here, or you may also find an answer on [Reverse Engineering](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: OK thanks. I was thinking more along the first two - so I won't ask here ;)

Comment: @W5VO what is the best way for OP to ask question?

Comment: @Chetan I'm not quite sure what you're asking...